# Message when suggesting edits to tag wikis seems to be incorrect

Tags: support, tags, reputation

[image]

As you can see it says you need 2000 rep to not have it peer reviewed, but you only actually need 750. Could this get fixed?

Comment: Swapped the tags here since this is by design and not a bug.

Comment: Could you add the status by design tag @SpencerG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message is correct. There are two different privileges:

- You need 750 reputation to be able to [peer review someone else's tag wiki edit](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits).
- You need 2000 reputation to [apply a tag wiki edit without it being peer reviewed](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).

Comment: Why are they different. Similar stuff like edit posts are the same

Comment: @Starship-OnStrike it seemed weird to me at first as well. But, it's SE's decision.

Comment: Like everything thats SEs decision its...to avoid violating the CoC...bad